# Pyodide - UI input instead of prompt

Tags: python-3.x, webassembly, pyodide

I am trying to run a python programming with pyodide, where the program has `x =input()`. This will ask the user input in prompt. Now I need to show the input in UI(DOM) await for input before executing next step as attached in the image.

[image]

Pyodide version:  v0.21.3

Comment: What is the actual question? Are the UI Input element and `input()` not linked together and not working?